# How to warn when you forget to `await` an async function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm using Babel and Webpack. If I forget to `await` an async function, it can often go unnoticed. Once in a while, if I forgot the `await`, an error occurs in the async function and I get an `Unhandled promise rejection`. Then, I realize that I forgot the `await`.

Is there a way to get a warning when I forget to add an `await`?

Comment: if you are using this a lot, build yourself a template that throws an error until all of the required stuff is provoided

Comment: If you're using ESLint, might the [`require-await`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-await) lint be enough for your needs? It won't catch imported async functions defined elsewhere but it will catch some cases

Comment: @Bojangles It will probably help a bit, but it definitely won't catch all the errors. I would like a way to require all async function calls to have an await before them.

Comment: `require all async function calls to have an await before them` - I wouldn't recommend you **require** it, *warning* would be sufficient, because it is perfectly valid not to require to await an `async` function - in fact, at least one place in your code would **have** to call a function tagged `async` **without** using `await`, because of the relationship between `await/async` keywords

Comment: @JaromandaX You're absolutely right. Also, awaiting an array of async functions would likely have async function calls without `await` directly in front of it (if we build the array dynamically). I guess what I'm looking for is a way to require `await` by default, but we can suppress the error explicitly. This way, it ensures that async functions calls without `await` were intentional.

Comment: `++` for ESLint, I'd say this is something that should be the task of your IDE.

Comment: @LeoJiang: Not only the case you describe. The first async function that gets called cannot be `await`ed because await is only valid inside async. So the first async function that gets called returns a promise that you must call `.then()` on. Other async functions that that async function then call can be awaited. That's why JaromandaX says there MUST be at least one place in your code without await

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think OP is looking for something like `no-floating-promises` from `tslint` see: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-floating-promises/

Comment: there is also an eslint variant: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md

Comment: They seem to have added it Jun 10, 2019. Two years after this answer was posted :)

Comment: Neither of these going to work if we don't use TypeScript right? Is there a comparable rule for JavaScript projects?

Answer (score 44):

The [`no-floating-promises`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-floating-promises/) ESLint rule requires you to explicitly handle any promises (e.g. with `await` or `void`).

Here's a minimal `.eslintrc` for use with TypeScript. Note that `parserOptions` is required for this rule:

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": { "project": "./tsconfig.json" },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": ["error"]
  }
}
```

(ESLint is recommended since TSLint has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint).)

(Credit to [@zaboco's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41685693/how-to-warn-when-you-forget-to-await-an-async-function-in-javascript#comment105712842_46374463))

Answer (score 9):

Setup better eslint integration with webpack, repo, and code editor.
Here is the applicable rule, [require await](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-await).

Consider integrating the following:

- [eslint loader](https://github.com/MoOx/eslint-loader) for webpack-level reporting
- eslint command line for CI/CD and local lint coverage
- code editor [inline linting](https://github.com/roadhump/SublimeLinter-eslint)

Comment: `require-await` doesn't really help. If the OP forgets to `await` a promise, he surely does also forget to make the function that should wait `async`.

Comment: While this is better than nothing, it also doesn't catch the case where you have an `async` function with multiple `await`s and you forget just a single one. It surprised me that eslint doesn't support a simple *always await async functions* rule but it turns out that this is quite complex to implement - see this thread https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9787