# Avoid knock-on refactoring, when a synchronous function suddenly needs an asynchronous value?

Tags: javascript, callback

While using javascript I keep running into situations, where previously synchronous code suddenly requires a value, that can only be obtained asynchronously.

For instance, I am working on a TamperMonkey script, where I have a function that operates on a string parsed from `location.hash`. Now I want to change the code to enable persistence across URL changes in a tab, by using the `GM_getTab(callback)` interface.

Since I need a couple of functions to be executed in unchanged order, a knock-on effect occurs, since I need to `await` the value and I suddenly end up refactoring several functions along the call-stack into `async` functions, until I reach a point, where the order needs no longer be guaranteed.

More importantly however, promises needing to be explicitly `await`ed, can lead to unexpected behavior, when an await is forgotten: E.g. `if(condition())` may suddenly always evaluate to `true`, and `'Hello '+getUserName()` may suddenly result in `Hello [object Promise]`.

Is there some way to avoid this "refactoring hell"?

### Simplified example

Subsequently, I present a heavily simplified example of what happened: Needing an `await` down the callstack, while needing to preserve the execution order lead to refactoring all the way up to the event callback `updateFromHash`.

```
// -- Before
function updateFromHash(){
    updateTextFromHash();
    updateTitleFromText();
}

function updateTextFromHash(){
    DISPLAY_AREA.innerText = getTextFromHash();
}

// -- After
async function updateFromHash(){
    await updateTextFromHash();
    updateTitleFromText();
}

async function updateTextFromHash(){
    DISPLAY_AREA.innerText = getTextFromHash()
        || await new Promise((accept,reject)=>GM_getTab(accept));        
}
```

In this case it is relatively simple, but I have previously seen the asynchronicity bubble up much farther in the call stack and cause unexpected behaviour, when an `await` was missed. The worst case I've seen was, when I suddenly needed the "DEBUG" flag to depend on an asynchronously stored user setting.

### Time Constraints

As pointed out by @DavidSampson, it would probably have been better in the example for the functions not to depend on mutable global state in the first place.

However, in practice code is written under time constraints, often by other people, and then you need a "small change" – but if that small change involves asynchrnous data in a formerly synchronous function, it would be desirable to minimize the refactoring effort. The solution needs to work *now*, cleaning up the design problem may have to wait until the next project meeting.

In the example given, refactoring is feasible, since it is a small, private TamperMonkey script. It ultimately only serves to illustrate the problem, but under commercial-project scenarios, cleaning up the code may not be feasible within a given project scope.

Comment: Closely related: [How not to forget using await everywhere in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45448272/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of general practices here that would minimize the effect of the problems you are having.

One thing is to try to write code that is not as dependent on happening in a specific order in the first place -- it can lead to a lot of headaches, as you see here.

```
async function updateFromHash(){
    await updateTextFromHash();
    updateTitleFromText();
}
```

Here you update some text in a global variable somewhere (more on that later), and then you call a function that goes and looks at that variable, and updates some other variable based on that. Obviously, if one has not finished happening, the other will not work properly.

But what if, instead, you retrieved the asynchronous data in a single place, and then dispatched both the `update` calls with the data they need as a function argument? Also, you can use `.then` chaining to deal with asynchronous data without having to make the function asynchronous.

```
async getHash(){
  return new Promise((accept,reject)=>GM_getTab(accept))
}
function setText(text){
  DISPLAY_AREA.innerText = text;
}
function setTitle(text){
  // make some modifications to the 'text' variable

  TITLE.innerText = myModifiedText // or whatever
}

function updateFromHash(){
  getHash()
     .then(text => {
               setText(text);
               setTitle(text); 
     // You could also call setTitle first, since they aren't dependent on each other
     });
}
```

Another improvement you could make is that, broadly speaking, it's often a good idea to keep your functions pure where possible -- the only things that they should modify on are things you pass in as arguments, and the only effects you expect from them are things that they `return`. Impurities must exist, for various reasons, but try to keep them on the sidelines of your code.

So in your example, you have a function that modifies a global variable, and then another function that presumably goes and looks at that variable, and changes *another* variable based on that information. This implicitly binds those two variables together, except it's not clear to the casual observer why that should be the case, and so it makes tracing bugs harder. One way you might handle your situation:

```
function createTitleFromText(text){
  // modify the text passed in to get the title you want
  return myModifiedText;
  // this function is pure
}

function updateContent(text){
  // This is now the ONLY function that modifies state
  // It also has nothing to do with *how* the text is retrieved
  TITLE_EL.innerText = createTitleFromText(text);
  DISPLAY_AREA.innerText = text;
}

async function getTextFromHash(){
  return new Promise((accept,reject)=>GM_getTab(accept))
}

// Then, somewhere else in your code
updateContent(await getTextFromHash());
```

It also might be a good idea to sprinkle in some object orientedness to this to make it more clear what owns what, and handle some of the ordering for you.

```
class Content {
  constructor(textEl, titleEl){
    this.textEl = textEl;
    this.titleEl = titleEl;
  }
  static createTitleFromText(text){
    //make modifications
     return myTitle;
  } 
  update(text){
    this.textEl.innerText = text;
    this.titleEl.innerText = Content.createTitleFromText(text);
  }
}

let myContent = new Content(DISPLAY_AREA, TITLE_EL);

// Later

myContent.update(await getTextFromHash());
```

There's not one right or wrong way, but these are some ideas you can play with.

As for stopping asynchronicity from bubbling up, using `.then` chaining is probably your best bet. Taking your original example:

```
// -- After
function updateFromHash(){
    updateTextFromHash()
      .then(updateTitleFromText);

}

async function updateTextFromHash(){
    DISPLAY_AREA.innerText = getTextFromHash()
        || await new Promise((accept,reject)=>GM_getTab(accept));        
}
```

Now `updateFromHash` can stay synchronous, but keep in mind that `updateFromHash` completing does NOT mean that `updateTitleFromText` is finished, or even that `updateTextFromHash` is finished. So you'll need to let the asynchronicity bubble up as far as is necessary to deal with any ordered effects.

There is unfortunately no way to synchronously `await`, due to the JS engine's single threaded nature -- if a synchronous function is waiting for something to finish, nothing else can run.

For particular cases though, you might be able to replicate that functionality synchronously, but it will also involve lots of refactoring.

You could, for example, define a property `DISPLAY_AREA.isValid = true`, and then in `updateTextFromHash`

```
DISPLAY_AREA.isValid = false;
DISPLAY_AREA.innerText = getTextFromHash()
        || await new Promise((accept,reject)=>GM_getTab(accept));
DISPLAY_AREA.isValid = true;
```

Then, in any code that needs `DISPLAY_AREA.innerText`, first check to see if that data is valid, and if it isn't, then `setTimeout` for some period of time and then check again.

Alternatively, you could also define a `DISPLAY_AREA.queuedActions = []`, and then your other functions can check the validity of `DISPLAY_AREA` and if it is false, add a callback to the `queuedActions`. Then `updateTextFromHash` looks like:

```
DISPLAY_AREA.isValid = false;
DISPLAY_AREA.innerText = getTextFromHash()
        || await new Promise((accept,reject)=>GM_getTab(accept));
for(var cb of DISPLAY_AREA.queuedActions){
  cb()
}
DISPLAY_AREA.isValid = true;
```

Of course, in most cases this would just lead to your invalidation logic bubbling up the way async/await does, but in some circumstances it might work out cleanly.

Comment: For clarification: In this particular case, the Tampermonkey script displays a "post-it note", when it finds a pattern such as `http://exaple.com/hello-world#xnote=TEXT`. But the note is also editable, and editing should update the hash. And whenever either one changes, the title of the tab should also be updated. Hence the code had grown into containing `updateTitleFromText`. In hindsight it would have been better for the two functions to be more independent, but given time constraints (in this case "a few minutes before going to bed, every coupld of days") ...

Comment: ... a clean solution may not be attainable in terms of "cost vs utility". In commercial project the constraint would more likely be "I've inherited thousands of lines of code, and I need the asynchronous value in this one synchronous function. Can I get a working solution until the next meeting, or do I need to justify a seemingly small change requring major refactoring?"

Comment: I added the constraint to the question.

Comment: I added some other options you might find helpful. Unfortunately the single threaded nature of JS makes it more or less impossible to strictly wait for asynchronous code without blocking other code from running.

Comment: *"more or less impossible to strictly wait for asynchronous code without blocking other code"* I suspect that this may not strictly be true (e.g. when a synchronous function is called as event handler), but that implementing the ability might have come at a high performance cost; A synchronous function that can use await would probably be equivalent to an asynchronous function that is await'ed by default.