# How to make synchronous HTTP GET request in JavaScript with axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
const axios = require('axios');
function load() {
  const response = axios.get('https://...');
  return response.data;
}
```

I can't make my function `async`. I need it to be declared exactly this way and return the data loaded from the URL via GET request.

Comment: Is this for nodejs or for the browser?

Comment: @t.niese it's for nodejs

Comment: Ok, and is there a particular reason why you can't make it asnyc?

Comment: @t.niese because all of my other functions in the program are "sync". I don't want to use `await` just because of axios

Comment: @yegor256 you simply cant.

Comment: @bill.gates maybe there is some workaround, with a waiting loop?

Comment: @yegor256 well it does not work with a loop for 1 reason. If you use an loop, your main thread is blocked. When your promise resolves, it wont get executed because the loop is blocked

Comment: You don't make synchronous network requests with JavaScript, point. With axios or otherwise. Deal with the asynchrony.

Comment: @bill.gates how functions like `execSync` and `spawnSync` work?

Comment: @yegor256 "*all of my other functions in the program are "sync".*" - you [shouldn't need to make *all* function asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45448272/1048572) in a well-designed program. Make those `async` where necessary, it shouldn't be a big deal. If you need help with that, please post the code of your program.

Comment: @yegor256 well isnt `exec` for running commands in a shell? maybe you could use it for an curl request

Comment: As you mention `spawnSync` you could spawn a child process with `spawnSync` do the request there and pass its result serialized to the parent process. But I really think this is a bad idea. That is completely against the concept of how nodejs is designed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can try using XMLhttprequest:

```
const XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

function syncRequest(url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url, false);
  xhr.send(null);
  return xhr.responseText;
}

(() => {
  const res = syncRequest("https://api.github.com/users/octocat");
})();
```

It will block until it receives an response

You will need to install the XMLHttprequest package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest

Comment: I agree with this approach

Answer (score 1):

suggestion: using `async` `await`

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function load() {
  const response = await axios.get('https://...');
  ...
}
```

Comment: I mentioned above that **I can't** make my function `async`